# set custom commands in Redis-cli

Tags: database, redis, command-line-interface

I manually execute a lot of commands at the Redis-cli for debugging purposes. I often do:

```
zrange zset 0 -1 withscores
```

and it'll return the items in zset for me to inspect. Is there a way to set a custom command so that I don't have to type that everytime? Redis documentation isn't very clear on this.

I was hoping there's something like:

```
var zsetrange = "zrange zset 0 -1 withscores"
```

then just call zsetrange to execute the custom commands. How do I do this?

Comment: you can use lua scripts, but I doubt that this will not be very useful for replacing a one liner

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably, no. `redis-cli` does not offer alias functionality atm, but feel free to ask for it in the mailing list or even better - contribute a PR that does it to the GitHub repository.